# The `import` support in Node.JS is a lie

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

The documentation states, that there is experimental ES6 module loader in Node.JS since version 10. I am waiting for this for a long time - loading of modules is the only thing that prevents me from smoothly using same code in browser and node.

My code:

```
import findNextBracket from "./BracketFinder.js";
```

How I start node:

```
node --experimental-modules ConvertToEs6Modules.js
```

How I get disappointed:

```
(node:7116) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
D:\web\lines\ConvertToEs6Modules.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import findNextBracket  from "./BracketFinder.js";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:54:15)
    at setExecutor (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:50:23)
```

Also Visual Studio hangs if you try to run such file in it, instead of showing the error above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files need to have the `.mjs` extension. [See the docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

> Once this has been set, files ending with `.mjs` will be able to be loaded as ES Modules.

Comment: Wow, who's stupid idea was that. Almost looks like they just don't want to allow the Node.js files to be compatible with browsers.

Comment: It's the result of a long process of deliberation, and this is the best alternative they could land on. [Here's a blog post detailing the process.](https://medium.com/@giltayar/native-es-modules-in-nodejs-status-and-future-directions-part-i-ee5ea3001f71)

Comment: @zero298 I linked to that exact page, did I not? 

Comment: My bad, sometimes the blue link text is hard to see.

Comment: The explanation on the blog makes no sense. Browsers do not need different extension, even though the specs also apply to them.

Comment: @TomášZato If that doesn't satisfy you, [there're plenty of issues on the repo for node ESM discussion.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/issues/57) Read through it and throw your hat in the ring if you like.

Comment: What's even worse, I tried to use symlink go to around this stupidity, but they resolve it to original name to prevent a workaround.